# SSIM (Structural similarity index measure) performance

Tags: image-processing, similarity, ssim

I have a reference image A and 2 target images B and C , I tried to measure the SSIM  as follows :

(from a human vision perception A & B are from the same class) and  A & C from different class.

```
result1 = SSIM(A , B) = 4.71027%;  
result2 = SSIM(A , C) =  7.95047%;
```

I used the code from opencv : [SSIM CODE](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.2.0/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/videoio/video-input-psnr-ssim/video-input-psnr-ssim.cpp)

I also tried LBP normalized histogram of the entire image by calculating KL divergence of the two histograms, but the results were worst.

Is there a way to measure the similarity without training?

Image A :
[image]

Image B :
[image]

Image C :
[image]

EDIT :

After @Cris Luengo suggestion, these are the results of 2 LBP versions Circular, and Variance-based. It' seems like the choice of the method (features descriptor) is critical:
(result = 0 means identical)

```
result1 = LPB_CIRCULAR_HIST_KL(A , B) =  0.66;
result2 = LPB_CIRCULAR_HIST_KL(A , C) =  0.64;

result1 = LPB_VAR_HIST_KL(A , B) = 0.49;
result2 = LPB_VAR_HIST_KL(A , C) = 3.74;
```

Comment: SSIM is to compare nearly identical images, differing only in noise or blur level. You want to compare texture, you need to use a texture measure. LBP is a good choice, but you might need to adjust its parameters. Note that A and B are rotated, so you need a rotationally invariant version of LBP.

Comment: Thank you. I used the extended LBP (circular), but I am not sure if that's enough for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As comments suggest, SSIM will not work if the two images are not pixel-alingned. You can find similarity between two unaligned images in a variety of ways. Nowadays one of the most popular is using CLIP. CLIP is what Generative AI like Stable Diffusion is based on.

I suggest you look at [this repo](https://github.com/openai/CLIP) which tells you how install CLIP for python and extract features and similarities. The example in there is for image-text similarity but you can extract image-image similarity by doing something like:

```py
import torch
import clip
from PIL import Image
import torch.nn.functional as F

device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
model, preprocess = clip.load("ViT-B/32", device=device)

image1 = preprocess(Image.open("Image1.png")).unsqueeze(0).to(device)
image2 = preprocess(Image.open("Image2.png")).unsqueeze(0).to(device)

with torch.no_grad():
    image1_features = model.encode_image(image1)
    image2_features = model.encode_image(image2)
    
    sim = F.cosine_similarity(image1_features, image2_features)
    
print("Cosine similarity: ", sim)
```

Note this might be quite slow depending on how many samples you have or what kind of task you want to run (brute force retrieval might not be feasible)

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a try. I am also curious whether this method can work using simpler models as well.

Comment: The last sentence is not complete.